# Why does OpenCV throw an UnsatisfiedLinkError when using Mat?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

When constructing a new `Mat` instance in OpenCV 3.2, the program throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. This happens both when invoking the `Mat` constructor directly, as well as when calling `Imgcodecs.imread`, which in turn throws an error on the following line:

```
Mat mats_mat = Converters.vector_Mat_to_Mat(mats);
```

The program is being run on a Mac running the latest version of macOS Sierra (10.12.3), and all available `dylib` files are located in the `java.library.path` directory. The file being read has been confirmed to exist. The stack trace reads (partially) as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:118)
```

The `dylib` files are loaded using the following code in `main` with no errors or warnings:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
System.loadLibrary("opencv_imgproc.3.2.0");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_imgcodecs.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_videoio.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_highgui.3.2.0");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_flann.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_ml.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_features2d.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_calib3d.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_objdetect.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_photo.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_stitching.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_video.3.2.0");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_superres.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_shape.3.2");
System.loadLibrary("opencv_videostab.3.2");
```

The error is thrown when performing any of the following actions:

```
this(Imgcodecs.imread(filePath));

Mat mat = new Mat();

MatOfPoint matOfPoint = new MatOfPoint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing out `Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME` on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04 w/ OpenCV 3.2 with Java and Python ports) gives me this:

```
opencv_java320
```

It seems to me that `System.load` requires a complete path whereas `Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME` only gives a partial name, not even including the extension! OpenCV Java has its default binary files path located at `/usr/local/share/OpenCV/java`. (At least for me or people who used the default settings when compiling) there you can find the library `libopencv_java320.so` which is the actual, correct native library you need to link to!